# How memory consumption in task bar increase on time in asp.net pages?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I am using a sample page where it fetches some data from SQL Server.

If I'm keeping the page idle for some time, the private working set and page faults increasing drastically.

I'm not performing any action but the values are changing continuously. This causes the page crashes after some time.

My questions are

1. Page fault is related to the site crash?
2. Which will cause the private working sets increase in idle time?
3. Do I need to decrease the recycling time for IIS application Pool?

Comment: What is your concern with respect to page faults?

Comment: I can see page fault is increasing in the range of 1000-8,000 in taskbar, this page fault is pointing to memory leak in application? If so , What makes it causing the private bytes increasing even idle time?

Comment: A page fault means that the OS didn't have the requested page in memory. You can't really say if anything is leaking from page faults alone. Your question doesn't have a lot of details so it is hard to say what is happening. When you see a crash do you see anything in logs? There should be an exception somewhere.